# run event code that highlights values but also the highlighting is mimicked in another range

Tags: excel, vba, events, highlighting

I am attaching a link

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b5m53erinmcj6ys/EXAMPLE.xlsm?dl=0

to view the file I have. Currently when selecting a combination on the column A it will highlight in the range to the right,  H5 to L27  the number that makes up the combination.

So my question is how can I mirror or mimic in the range to the right of the first range H5 to L27, meaning the cells that get highlighted in the first range  get highlighted in the same cells in the second range  Q5 to U27.  right now it doesn't matter the data in the second range, as the second range is just mimicking  the first range of cells be highlighted in yellow.

(the first one is done to show what it should be doing)

the code I have so far is this for  mimicking one cell from one range to the other but am stuck and can't make it work to mimic all five cells at a time. here is the code,

```
[Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)    With Target
    If .Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("H:L")) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Union(.Cells(1, 1), .Offset(0, 9)).Select
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("Q:V")) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Union(.Cells(1, 1), .Offset(0, -9)).Select
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("Z:AD")) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Union(.Cells(1, 1), .Offset(0, -9)).Select
            Application.EnableEvents = True




   End If
End If
End With
```

End Sub]

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!
Sincerely Dennis

Comment: When you open the link you’ll see the the excel sheet, in column A there are combinations, I select the combinations from top to bottom one at a time, as I do this the numbers in the first range highlight the numbers that make up the combinations. Run you lee see how it works.

Comment: When you open the link you’ll see the the excel sheet, in column A there are combinations, I select the combinations from top to bottom one at a time, as I do this the numbers in the first range highlight the numbers that make up the combinations. Run you lee see how it works.    So now you ll see the range of data in regards to the white and red cells interior color is the same. So what I need is help getting the cells to get highlighted in yellow in the same areas so the highlighted are indentical.  The first one one in column A is selected now look at the numbers in H to L, Q to U

Comment: Review the excel sheet in the link I provided, look atccolumn A then look at Range H to L , then look at Q to U. Now th data in the Q to U column stays there but has no involvement in the cells that get colored interior yellow. The Q to U is only acting out what happens when the event code runs in the H to L.

Comment: I would like to incorporate the code above into existing event code but improve it by having it so it works in the description in the added commentary